# Passing value to state - redux

Tags: reactjs, redux

I created a calculator in react. Now I would like to use the global instead of the local state - I know that this solution may not have a larger session, but I want to learn redux in this way. I prepared the action and the reducer. I don't know how to pass the values - I get an error with a non-existent result variable.
Link to application with local status:
https://codesandbox.io/s/calculator-9dq6i?file=/src/Calc.js:691-705

Link to application with redux:
https://codesandbox.io/s/gifted-shirley-uonew?file=/src/reducers/index.js:0-292

Code:
index.js

```
import React from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import { createStore } from "redux";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import App from "./components/App";
import calculate from "./reducers";

const store = createStore(calculate);

render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <App />
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

reducer - index.js

```
const calculate = (state, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "ADD_TO_MEMORY":
      result += id;
      return result;

    case "ADD":
      result = parseFloat(result) + parseFloat(prev);
      return result;

    default:
      return result;
  }
};

export default calculate;
```

action - index.js

```
let prev = "";
let result = "";
let current = "";
let disabled = true;

export const addToMemory = id => ({
  type: "ADD_TO_MEMORY",
  result: result
});

export const add = result => ({
  type: "ADD",
  result: result
});
```

App.js

```
import React from "react";
import Counter from "./Counter";

const App = () => (
  <div>
    <Counter />
  </div>
);

export default App;
```

Counter.js

```
import React from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { addToMemory, add } from "../actions/index";

const Counter = ({ dispatch, result }) => {
  return (
    <p>
      <button id="1" onClick={addToMemory("1")}>
        1
      </button>
      <button id="1" onClick={addToMemory("2")}>
        2
      </button>
      <button id="1" onClick={addToMemory("3")}>
        3
      </button>
      <button id="1" onClick={addToMemory("4")}>
        4
      </button>
      <button id="1" onClick={addToMemory("5")}>
        5
      </button>
      <button id="1" onClick={addToMemory("6")}>
        6
      </button>
      <button id="1" onClick={addToMemory("7")}>
        7
      </button>
      <button id="1" onClick={addToMemory("8")}>
        8
      </button>
      <button id="1" onClick={addToMemory("9")}>
        9
      </button>
      <button id="1" onClick={addToMemory("0")}>
        0
      </button>
      <p>RESULT: {result}</p>
    </p>
  );
};

export default connect()(Counter);
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps I can clear up some of the fundamental misunderstandings here and that might help set you on the right track.

You are on the right track, but there are some changes to be made:

1. You need to both `mapDispatchToProps` and `mapStateToProps` in order to do what you're looking to do in your `Counter.js` file. `mapStateToProps` will let you tell Redux, "What state do I need to access inside my component?" Similarly, `mapDispatchToProps` will let you tell Redux, "Which action creators do I need to access inside my component?"

Here, you need to access presumably `state.result` for your state, so your `mapStateToProps` might look something like this:

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
   result: state.result
})
```

Similarly, `mapDispatchToProps` might look like this:

```
const mapDispatchToProps = {
   addToMemory
}
```

Then you can link it with:

```
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Counter);
```

You can then access it inside your component by doing `({result, addToMemory})` to *destructure* those props and use them in the `Counter` component.

2. Your reducer is a *function* which takes two parameters: the previous state and the action object, and returns a brand new state. This **must not** modify any existing variables. It has to return new information. See the [docs](https://redux.js.org/basics/reducers#handling-actions) for more information. When you dispatch `addToMemory`, it has two fields in the object: `type` and `result`. In your reducer, you can access these by doing `action.type` and `action.result` respectively. That's why you're getting that error.
3. In your `action/index.js` file your `add` action creator takes an `id` but references `result`. Change the parameter to take `result` instead so that you don't have an error there as well.

Might be helpful when debugging to do some `console.log` statements of different variables or use the Redux DevTools Chrome extension to help debug some of the issues.